# Why do I get the error "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" when running the sppba function of the WRS2 package?

Tags: r, debugging

I would be super grateful for some help. I don't have a coding background and I am confused by the error message I am getting when running the sppb functions of the WRS2 package. These functions perform a robust mixed ANOVA using bootstrapping.

sppba(formula = score ~ my_between_variable * my_within_variable, id = participant_code, data = df_long_T2)

```
Error in xmat[, k] <- x[[kv]] : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I get the same error for all three sppb functions. The functions look the same except that instead of sppba the others say sppbb and sppbi. I don't even know what the functions are trying to replace. The functions work for me with other data.

The classes of all the things involved seem fine: score is numeric, order_supplement and time are factors, participant_code is character, df_long_T2 is a dataframe. I have 120 participants, 61 in one group and 59 in the other, with two observations per participant. There are no NAs in the columns involved.

Traceback() just gives me the one line of code above and the error message.

Debug() gives me this and I don't know what to make of it:
"Debug location is approximate because location is not available"

```
function (formula, id, data, est = "mom", avg = TRUE, nboot = 500, 
  MDIS = FALSE, ...) 
{
  if (missing(data)) {
    mf <- model.frame(formula)
  }
  else {
    mf <- model.frame(formula, data)
  }
  cl <- match.call()
  est <- match.arg(est, c("mom", "onestep", "median"), several.ok = FALSE)
  mf1 <- match.call()
  m <- match(c("formula", "data", "id"), names(mf1), 0L)
  mf1 <- mf1[c(1L, m)]
  mf1$drop.unused.levels <- TRUE
  mf1[[1L]] <- quote(stats::model.frame)
  mf1 <- eval(mf1, parent.frame())
  random1 <- mf1[, "(id)"]
  depvar <- colnames(mf)[1]
  if (all(length(table(random1)) == table(mf[, 3]))) {
    ranvar <- colnames(mf)[3]
    fixvar <- colnames(mf)[2]
  }
  else {
    ranvar <- colnames(mf)[2]
    fixvar <- colnames(mf)[3]
  }
  MC <- FALSE
  K <- length(table(mf[, ranvar]))
  J <- length(table(mf[, fixvar]))
  p <- J * K
  grp <- 1:p
  est <- get(est)
  fixsplit <- split(mf[, depvar], mf[, fixvar])
  indsplit <- split(mf[, ranvar], mf[, fixvar])
  dattemp <- mapply(split, fixsplit, indsplit, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
  data <- do.call(c, dattemp)
  x <- data
  jp <- 1 - K
  kv <- 0
  kv2 <- 0
  for (j in 1:J) {
    jp <- jp + K
    xmat <- matrix(NA, ncol = K, nrow = length(x[[jp]]))
    for (k in 1:K) {
      kv <- kv + 1
      xmat[, k] <- x[[kv]]
    }
    xmat <- elimna(xmat)
    for (k in 1:K) {
      kv2 <- kv2 + 1
      x[[kv2]] <- xmat[, k]
    }
  }
  xx <- x
  nvec <- NA
  jp <- 1 - K
  for (j in 1:J) {
    jp <- jp + K
    nvec[j] <- length(x[[jp]])
  }
  bloc <- matrix(NA, nrow = J, ncol = nboot)
  mvec <- NA
  ik <- 0
  for (j in 1:J) {
    x <- matrix(NA, nrow = nvec[j], ncol = K)
    for (k in 1:K) {
      ik <- ik + 1
      x[, k] <- xx[[ik]]
      if (!avg) 
        mvec[ik] <- est(xx[[ik]])
    }
    tempv <- apply(x, 2, est)
    data <- matrix(sample(nvec[j], size = nvec[j] * nboot, 
      replace = TRUE), nrow = nboot)
    bvec <- matrix(NA, ncol = K, nrow = nboot)
    for (k in 1:K) {
      temp <- x[, k]
      bvec[, k] <- apply(data, 1, rmanogsub, temp, est)
    }
    if (avg) {
      mvec[j] <- mean(tempv)
      bloc[j, ] <- apply(bvec, 1, mean)
    }
    if (!avg) {
      if (j == 1) 
        bloc <- bvec
      if (j > 1) 
        bloc <- cbind(bloc, bvec)
    }
  }
  if (avg) {
    d <- (J^2 - J)/2
    con <- matrix(0, J, d)
    id <- 0
    Jm <- J - 1
    for (j in 1:Jm) {
      jp <- j + 1
      for (k in jp:J) {
        id <- id + 1
        con[j, id] <- 1
        con[k, id] <- 0 - 1
      }
    }
  }
  if (!avg) {
    MJK <- K * (J^2 - J)/2
    JK <- J * K
    MJ <- (J^2 - J)/2
    cont <- matrix(0, nrow = J, ncol = MJ)
    ic <- 0
    for (j in 1:J) {
      for (jj in 1:J) {
        if (j < jj) {
          ic <- ic + 1
          cont[j, ic] <- 1
          cont[jj, ic] <- 0 - 1
        }
      }
    }
    tempv <- matrix(0, nrow = K - 1, ncol = MJ)
    con1 <- rbind(cont[1, ], tempv)
    for (j in 2:J) {
      con2 <- rbind(cont[j, ], tempv)
      con1 <- rbind(con1, con2)
    }
    con <- con1
    if (K > 1) {
      for (k in 2:K) {
        con1 <- push(con1)
        con <- cbind(con, con1)
      }
    }
  }
  if (!avg) 
    bcon <- t(con) %*% t(bloc)
  if (avg) 
    bcon <- t(con) %*% (bloc)
  tvec <- t(con) %*% mvec
  tvec <- tvec[, 1]
  tempcen <- apply(bcon, 1, mean)
  vecz <- rep(0, ncol(con))
  bcon <- t(bcon)
  temp = bcon
  for (ib in 1:nrow(temp)) temp[ib, ] = temp[ib, ] - tempcen + 
    tvec
  bcon <- rbind(bcon, vecz)
  if (!MDIS) {
    if (!MC) 
      dv = pdis(bcon, center = tvec)
  }
  if (MDIS) {
    smat <- var(temp)
    bcon <- rbind(bcon, vecz)
    chkrank <- qr(smat)$rank
    if (chkrank == ncol(smat)) 
      dv <- mahalanobis(bcon, tvec, smat)
    if (chkrank < ncol(smat)) {
      smat <- ginv(smat)
      dv <- mahalanobis(bcon, tvec, smat, inverted = T)
    }
  }
  bplus <- nboot + 1
  sig.level <- 1 - sum(dv[bplus] >= dv[1:nboot])/nboot
  tvec1 <- data.frame(Estimate = tvec)
  if (avg) {
    tnames <- apply(combn(levels(mf[, fixvar]), 2), 2, paste0, 
      collapse = "-")
    rownames(tvec1) <- tnames
  }
  else {
    fixcomb <- apply(combn(levels(mf[, fixvar]), 2), 2, 
      paste0, collapse = "-")
    rnames <- levels(mf[, ranvar])
    tnames <- as.vector(t(outer(rnames, fixcomb, paste)))
    rownames(tvec1) <- tnames
  }
  result <- list(test = tvec1, p.value = sig.level, contrasts = con, 
    call = cl)
  class(result) <- c("spp")
  result
}
```

I expected to get an output like this:

```
## Test statistics:
##                              Estimate
## time1-time2   0.3000
## 
## Test whether the corrresponding population parameters are the same:
## p-value: 0.37
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you have already solved your problem, but I've stumbled upon the same issue in these days.
I've tried to re-factor all the variables (id, between-factor and within-factor), but nothing worked until I've focus my attention on the NAs I had in the dependent variable.
I've managed to make sppbb, sppba and sppbi work by replacing every NA with another value.
Changing the dataframe with na.omit() didn't work.
So, I think there is some problem in how those functions handle NAs.
Hope this is useful.

EDIT:
Here a more articulated response, hoping to be useful (although it could be granted in some steps):

1. start with your original data
   1a) convert into factor your ID, between factor and within factor columns
   1b) convert into numeric your score column
2. check whether there are missing values or NA in your dependent variable
   2a) if no, proceed to the next step
   2b) if yes, replace them (just to see it they are the problem, you could replace them with 0. Otherwise, try multiple imputation or another approach useful to handle missing data)
3. check whether there are all the possible combinations of your between (BF) and within factors (WF)
   3a) e.g., let's suppose that you have 2 participants, the BF has 2 levels and the WF has 3 levels. Then make sure that you have complete cases like the table below

```
| ID | BF         | WF         | score |
|----|------------|------------|-------|
| 1  | BF_level_1 | WF_level_1 | value |
| 1  | BF_level_1 | WF_level_2 | value |
| 1  | BF_level_1 | WF_level_3 | value |
| 2  | BF_level_2 | WF_level_1 | value |
| 2  | BF_level_2 | WF_level_2 | value |
| 2  | BF_level_2 | WF_level_3 | value |
```

3b) if not, add rows to have all the possible combinations and then replace missing scores as in 2b)
4) if you subset your data before running those functions
4a) refactorize your ID, BF, and WF columns
4b) make sure that the subsetted data: does not have NAs or missing values; shows every possible combination for your BF and WF
4c) if the subsetted data has NAs or lacks some combination of your factors, solve them as in 2b) or 3b)
5) then, run those functions
For what I have understood, I think that, if there NAs or missing combinations among factors, those functions can't run properly.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34238290)

Comment: Hi @MatthieuH,
To tell you the truth, I do not understand your comment.

Although I don't know whether my answer is useful for everyone, it does answer the question.

To put it simply, I made those functions work, thus obtaining the expected output posted by curious, by replacing every NA with other values.

I apologise if I was not clear with my first post.

Comment: It is clearly specified  in the question that `There are no NAs in the columns involved` so there is no reason to think that the problem comes from the NA values.

Comment: You could have written that sooner: it would have more clear to me.
I've edited my response to be more clear and to describe a process that I hope could help resolve the problem.
Although curious said there aren't NAs, another check is always useful since, when programming, many things can slip from us.
On the other hand, maybe there are NAs or missing data in the original data – as I said, na.omit() did not work for me. Therefore, if curious obtained the data in that way, a complete check regarding missing values, NAs, or factor combinations starting could maybe be useful.